# python numpy pairwise edit-distance

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, lambda, pdist

So, I have a numpy array of strings, and I want to calculate the pairwise edit-distance between each pair of elements using this function: scipy.spatial.distance.pdist from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

A sample  of my array is as follows:

```
 >>> d[0:10]
 array(['TTTTT', 'ATTTT', 'CTTTT', 'GTTTT', 'TATTT', 'AATTT', 'CATTT',
   'GATTT', 'TCTTT', 'ACTTT'], 
  dtype='|S5')
```

However, since it doesn't have the 'editdistance' option, therefore, I want to give a customized distance function. I tried this and I faced the following error:

```
 >>> import editdist
 >>> import scipy
 >>> import scipy.spatial
 >>> scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(d[0:10], lambda u,v: editdist.distance(u,v))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/epd-7.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 1150, in pdist
    [X] = _copy_arrays_if_base_present([_convert_to_double(X)])
  File "/usr/local/epd-7.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 153, in _convert_to_double
    X = np.double(X)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: TTTTT
```

Comment: looks like it just isn't designed for strings. you might want to look into https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Comment: That error line is the 2nd line in `pdist`.  So you will have convert your strings to some sort of number before passing them to `pdist`.  Also `pdist` wants a 2D array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really must use `pdist`, you first need to convert your strings to numeric format. If you know that all strings will be the same length, you can do this rather easily:

```
numeric_d = d.view(np.uint8).reshape((len(d),-1))
```

This simply views your array of strings as a long array of `uint8` bytes, then reshapes it such that each original string is on a row by itself. In your example, this would look like:

```
In [18]: d.view(np.uint8).reshape((len(d),-1))
Out[18]:
array([[84, 84, 84, 84, 84],
       [65, 84, 84, 84, 84],
       [67, 84, 84, 84, 84],
       [71, 84, 84, 84, 84],
       [84, 65, 84, 84, 84],
       [65, 65, 84, 84, 84],
       [67, 65, 84, 84, 84],
       [71, 65, 84, 84, 84],
       [84, 67, 84, 84, 84],
       [65, 67, 84, 84, 84]], dtype=uint8)
```

Then, you can use `pdist` as you normally would. Just make sure that your `editdist` function is expecting arrays of integers, rather than strings. You could quickly convert your new inputs by calling `.tostring()`:

```
def editdist(x, y):
  s1 = x.tostring()
  s2 = y.tostring()
  ... rest of function as before ...
```

Comment: ... or do the edit distance directly on the `uint8`s.

Answer (score -4):

```html
def my_pdist(data,f):
    N=len(data)
    matrix=np.empty([N*(N-1)/2])
    ind=0
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i+1,N):
            matrix[ind]=f(data[i],data[j])
            ind+=1
    return matrix
```

Comment: Providing some context, additional information regarding how this is an answer for the question, would be helpful and beneficial not only to the original asker of the question, but future visitors to this solution.

A raw, "code-only" snippet isn't the best form of an answer.