# Find most repeated log lines in a large log file, fuzzy match

Tags: apache-spark, logging, duplicates, fuzzy-search

I have a program that produces about ~5 million lines of logs per hour (~1400 lines / second). That's about 650MB. About 99.9999% of it is from library we use (apache-spark / Databricks).

How can I run some kind of fuzzy duplicate identifier on this file to identify most repeated log lines? So I can silence them in my log4j2 config.

Most of these logs are useless even when something does go wrong, and it's causing a lot of problems with disk space, log processing (grafana), alerts etc.

I saw [Pandas fuzzy detect duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490190/pandas-fuzzy-detect-duplicates), but it seems like something that works on a lot more structured data.

Comment: @LakshayRohila, I think you missed the part that this is log file and we're talking about fuzzy match, not exact. Given that every line in a log file has a timestamp with microseconds precision, `uniq` will not find a single duplicate and will print all 4 million rows from the log file.